# RadFilter - How to Apply Expression programmatically

Tags: asp.net, telerik, filtering, radgrid

I have a RadFilter that response to the RadGrid. I've successfully do the RadFilter.SaveSettings to save the RadFilter state into the database and RadFilter.LoadSettings to load the RadFilter back.

However, after loaded the RadFilter, I need to click on the 'Apply' button to refresh my RadGrid list. May I know if there is any way I can trigger the filtering of the RadGrid automatically after the RadFilter.LoadSetting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find any useful function on this, I do a workaround. In which on Apply Expression event, always store the filter expression in a hidden field.

```
protected void rftWarehouseItem_ApplyExpressions(object sender, RadFilterApplyExpressionsEventArgs e)
        {
            RadFilterSqlQueryProvider provider = new RadFilterSqlQueryProvider();
            provider.ProcessGroup(e.ExpressionRoot);

            hdfFilterExpression.Value = provider.Result;

            rgdWarehouseItem.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = provider.Result;
            rgdWarehouseItem.Rebind();
        }
```

During the saving into database, I will store the hdfFilterExpression.Value in the database. When the record is retrieve again from the database, just rebind the gridview.

```
rgdWarehouseItem.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = record.FilterExpression;
rgdWarehouseItem.Rebind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do :

```
this.RadFilter1.FireApplyCommand();
```

P.s. Change `RadFilter1` for your object name.